# How to position buttons inside a scrollview using kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have some buttons inside a gridlayout in a scrollView that move vertically. I have been trying to postion those buttons at different positions but they are not changing. Please how do I position those buttons at different x and y coordinate. I used floatlayout but it is not working for ScrollView(), why is that?

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class ScrollViewApp(App):
    def build(self):

        grid = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=90, size_hint=(None,None))   
        grid.bind(minimum_height=grid.setter('height'))
   

            btn1=Button(text='1', size=(90,90), size_hint=(None,None), pos_hint={'center_x':.5, 'center_y': 6})
            btn2=Button(text='1', size=(90,90), size_hint=(None,None), pos_hint={'center_x':.5, 'center_y': 2})
            btn3=Button(text='1', size=(90,90), size_hint=(None,None), pos_hint={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.9})

        grid.add_widget(btn1)
         grid.add_widget(btn2)
         grid.add_widget(btn3)

# pos_hint={center_x and center_y} not working 
        scroll = ScrollView( size_hint=(1, 1), do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, scroll_type=['content'])
        scroll.effect_cls= 'ScrollEffect'
        scroll.add_widget(grid)

        return scroll


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

to do this you can either give the each input of the x and y coordinate yourself:

```
for i in range(15):
        a = float(input(f"Enter X postion value for #00{i}: "))
        b = float(input(f"Enter Y postion value for #00{i}: "))
        screen.add_widget(Button(text='#00' + str(i), size=(90,90), size_hint=(None,None),pos_hint={'center_x':a, 'center_y':b} ))
```

or

You can `import random` and set the different values or use "for" loop to insert different sequential values. I am showing you the examples 'random' below here:

```
        for i in range(15):
            a = random.randrange(0,10)
            b = random.randrange(1,20)
            screen.add_widget(Button(text='#00' + str(i), size=(90,90), size_hint=(None,None),pos_hint={'center_x':a, 'center_y':b} ))
```

I hope this will help you. And I am not sure about the usage of grid layouts here. You try to remove gridlayouts and just placing these buttons on different coordinate as you have gave the value for spacing of the button in the grid layout which may affect the output display. So, I hope it will work for you. Happy Coding...

Comment: thanks for your response but the code didn't work, the buttons didn't change position, I think pos_hint doesn't work for scrollview. So how do I position maybe just a single button and which layout can I use in scrollview to achieve this

Comment: Don't use scrollview and gridlayout it will work. I have added the code as another answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import random


class ScrollViewApp(App):
       def build(self):

           screen = Screen()

           for i in range(3):
                   a = float(input(f"Enter X postion value for #00{i}: "))
                   b = float(input(f"Enter Y postion value for #00{i}: "))
                   screen.add_widget(Button(text='#00' + str(i), size=(90,90), size_hint=(None,None),pos_hint={'center_x':a, 'center_y':b} ))

              return screen

if __name__ == '__main__':
       ScrollViewApp().run()
```

This one works fine. I hope this will help you....

Comment: make sure the value of pos_hint is between 0 to 1.

Comment: thanks for your response, it seems you are not getting me.  I am using 'ScrollView()', which means the screen will scroll vertically Upward.  So my problem is how do I position different buttons at different positions inside the ScrollView.  (without for loop)  I would appreciate if I can get a sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

float layout should certainly work in scrollview, here's an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import random

class ScrollViewApp(App):
    def build(self):

        float = FloatLayout(size=(600,1000),size_hint=(None,None))
        for i in range(20):
            btn1=Button(text=str(i), size=(90,90), size_hint=(None,None), pos_hint={'center_x':random.random(), \
                'center_y': random.random()})
            float.add_widget(btn1)

        scroll = ScrollView( size_hint=(.8, .3), do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, scroll_y=0.5,scroll_type=['content','bars'],\
            bar_color = [1,0,0,.9],bar_inactive_color=[1,0,0.3,.5],bar_width=25)
        scroll.add_widget(float)

        return scroll


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

whereas with the attempted gridlayout, the position of each button will be at regular intervals, at least by default. To get arbitrary offsets at each cell of a gridlayout might be possible, but it would be three times as much work at least as just using float layout.

Note that the size_hint for the float layout is None,None, and the absolute size (600,1000) is intentionally larger than the scrollview (fractional 0.8,0.3 of default Window.size()). Scroll behaviour won't be seen otherwise.